# The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type on dio new package version

Tags: flutter, dio

I have upgraded my DIO package to 5.0.0 and I am getting the following error on my api client test file:
[...]

```
(server) {
          server.throws(
            400,
            DioException(
              type: DioErrorType.response,
              requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: route),
            ),
          );
        },
```

[...]
Error: The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DioExceptionType'.
What should we use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DioExceptionType.badResponse` instead of `DioErrorType.response`

Now in `dio 5.0.0`, `DioErrorType` has different values.
You can check [this commit](https://github.com/cfug/dio/pull/1637/commits/090f18fed59eeb2fde9eea41f314318f3c638367#diff-6a0ef3bc5c3c0118260a04e4aec848ca9643fb03eebc974d61d38f8aef13101c) or
[this changelog](https://github.com/cfug/dio/blob/3471b7a1b2d5a927a4ef76876f80b3704cf3d38a/dio/CHANGELOG.md) (changelog content for this issue is not detailed in main branch)

`DioError` was deprecated in [dio 5.2.0](https://github.com/cfug/dio/releases/tag/dio_v5.2.0). so you should use `DioExceptionType` instead `DioErrorType`.